# Internet Explorer 6 background-color

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I have used the code below to divide the pages into two halves, 28% and 72%. But the background color set by the wrapper tag should fill 28%; in my case it works fine in [Internet Explorer 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7).

In [Internet Explorer 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6), the background color is visible across 100% of the width instead of 28%.

How do I fix this?

#### My code:

```
#wrapper{ 
    float:left; 
    width:28%;
    background:#f5f5dc;  
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="testnav">
        <li>  <a href="#">LOCATIONS</a>
            <ul id="subnav">
                <li id="content_1"><a href="#">Note </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what the exact problem is? What is the code doing that it shouldn't be doing?

Comment: Brian, I think there's ample precedent that CSS stuff is programming related (of interest to programmers is how the FAQ puts it). That's why I reverted your tag away.

Comment: Above code works fine in IE6. Can you post more inof also please chekc your other questions. Tere are lot of commments and all your questions dont have enough infromation.

Comment: And BTW "problem" is not a tag.

Comment: It works as expected in IE6 (6.0.2600.0000.xpclient.010817-1148) as well. Is this the only markup in your html?

Comment: Changing the question title from 'Problem in ie6' to something more specific would benefit yourself (the question asker) and others looking for a solution to the same problem.

Comment: Yellowish background fills out only 28% of the page or did you want to have it fill 28% of just the wrapper it's in?

Answer (score 0):

It is an ancient Internet Explorer bug, and it happens only if there is *both* of complex [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and complex [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML). For example, in https://drupal.org/node/129014 it happened, too.

What worked me: I specified background-color on both of the parent and the child (in your case, #wrapper), and both [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) nodes also got a zoom: 1.